# input data in a plugin during a loop - imageJ - Java

Tags: java, jquery-plugins, imagej

Totally new to Java,
I have a stack of image that I need to change with ImageJ,
I wrote a script that does what I need but I would like to add the plugin function Stack_Normalizer.class, that you can find here https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/normalizer.html

After I run the function it asks me to input the minimum and maximum values wanted (always the same in may case), since I have many thousands images I cannot to it manually, how can I set this values automatically in the pup up window? I tried setMinimum, setMaximum but no success.
Here is part of the loop:

```
makeRectangle(126, 20, 433, 422);
run("Crop");
run("Stack Normalizer");
```

here I need to set the values in the pop up window.
Then the loop continue...

```
run("8-bit");
setThreshold(0,79);
run("Threshold");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, to input value in the pop-up window it's enough to add the following when calling the function:

```
run( "Stack Normalizer", "minimum=22 maximum=220" )
```